# Xbox to Robot Inventor?

Tags: compatibility, remote-control, bluetooth, robot-inventor

Is it possible to connect an Xbox controller directly to the Lego Robot Inventor(51515) intelligent brick?

Answer (score 2):

In 2024, Pybricks added the ability to connect an XBox controller directly to hubs that are running the 3rd-party Pybricks firmware. This works with MINDSTORMS Robot Inventor, SPIKE Prime, SPIKE Essential and the 4-port Technic hub.

Comment: Deleted my answer in favor of this one. Xbox control of Lego models through PyBricks is awesome!